# How to create a complex user-defined type in HSQLDB?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

How to create a complex user-defined type in *HSQLDB*?

**Oracle syntax:**

```
CREATE TYPE type_name AS OBJECT(
  one VARCHAR2(255),
  two VARCHAR2(255),
  three NUMBER(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

HSQLDB does not support user defined types with more than a single attribute (member).